# How can we add columns to an existing table in aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-cloud9

I am new to using AWS CDK. How can we add columns to an existing table in dynamodb using aws cdk. Using boto3 resources, there is an option of update_item in table. Could I use an alternative to use my sort_key to assign more than one columns or is there a better alternate?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I tried using SET to add columns according to my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "columns" in DynamoDB as it is schema-less. Apart from `primary` and `sort` keys, every item can have fully independent attributes and structure. So you can use `update_item` to add new attributes to existing item, or remove them.